# Is switching customs allowed?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

To what extent are, say, Ashkenazic Jews halachically obligated to follow Ashkenazic customs by, say, refraining from eating kitniyot on Pessah?  Chullin 110a-b says: Follow the restrictions of the place from which you come AND the restrictions of the place where you are.  But what does halacha say on the matter?  And does it make a difference whether the switch is total or selective, temporary or permanent?

Comment: The requirement to follow the strictures of both places is only regarding someone who is staying there temporarily. A person who moves permanently from a community in Ashkenaz to one in Sepharad, would abandon all his Ashkenazi customs, whether lenient or stringent.  Note, however, there are opinions (e.g. the Ritva) that the custom of refraining from kitniyot is an errant custom (*minhag taut*) and therefore not even binding in Ashkenaz.

Comment: Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60576/759

Comment: @DoubleAA on the second thought, while it is a duplicate, the other question is ill-defined and ill-answered ("I was told"). Let's hope somebody will answer this one better.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not a dupe. The other question specifically asks Seph-to-Ashko. This seems to be asking the opposite. Frankly, I think more complete questions and answers would be if switching customs from any A to any B is permitted (and according to who).

Comment: @Lee the fact that each chose the opposite example doesn't seem relevant. Just like this question isn't only about kitniyot.